# Creating a resized image file (thumbnail)

Tags: asp.net

On my website users can upload photos.
on the main view of the website, those photos are displayed as thumbnails and on click the user is redirected to the full sized image.

currently, I display the thumbnails by using the original (large) files, that are resized in CSS. This means that the user has to download the entire file (something over 3 MB) per image, before the thumbnails appear.

on a page with 50 thumbnails this could prove impractical.

is there a way to create a duplicate smaller image that is resized and thus weighs much less?

for example, facebook uses this as the thumbnail
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/276906_21785951839_381903312_q.jpg

and this as the full sized image:
https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/734249_10151197598341840_489922283_n.png

How can I achieve the same thing using asp.net?

what should I read?

Comment: Have you tried google for that!? here is the first result in bing for resizing images in asp.net http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/48350/Resizing-images-in-ASP-NET-using-GDI

Comment: How about using ImageResizer: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer

Comment: ImageResizer is the way to go